# is it necessary to have URDF model for diff_drive_controller

Tags: ros, diff-drive-controller, ros-control, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am building a differential drive robot and trying to exploit the power of ros_control by using the diff_drive_controller into my project

I have found that I have to fulfill some hardware requirements to the controller in order to be able to use it  and that's what I have done but due to my limited knowledge in URDF and TF I can't understand the part of the left_wheel_joint and right_wheel_joint in the configuration of the controller

shall I first make a URDF model of my robot to be able to use the diff_drive_controller or I can just make a TF to use or it's not possible?
what shall I write in the following parameters?

```
left_wheel
right_wheel
```

I will appreciate your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300763/is-it-necessary-to-have-urdf-model-for-diff_drive_controller/) by [ShehabAldeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/31455/shehabaldeen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2018-08-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-16**:
Please change the title of your question.

The title makes it seem like you want to know whether urdf is required for TF *in general*, but your question text appears to be asking whether a urdf is needed for use with `diff_drive_controller`.

Those are two different things.

**Comment by [ShehabAldeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/31455/shehabaldeen/) on 2018-08-16**:
Yes I missed that sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it's necessary to have a URDF. The parameters `left_wheel` and `right_wheel` need to be set to the joint names from the URDF.

In your URDF, you also need a transmission for that joint. If you want to look at an example, in my [mir_robot](https://github.com/dfki-ric/mir_robot) stack I use the `diff_drive_controller` (but only in Gazebo, not on the real robot). I have converted the xacro to a URDF (using `xacro --inorder mir.urdf.xacro > mir.urdf`) and deleted a couple of things that are not relevant to your question. The result is here:

https://gist.github.com/mintar/5d8e60a145ec80643d3ea82544c2c233

You can see that there is one joint for each wheel and a transmission for both. There are also four caster wheels; you don't need them of course if your robot doesn't have them. Note that you need to run `sudo apt install ros-kinetic-mir-description` if you want to try the URDF.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2018-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ShehabAldeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/31455/shehabaldeen/) on 2018-08-17**:
Thank you for your help and for sure I will use your URDF code as a reference to write my own
Thank you for your time

**Comment by [ShehabAldeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/31455/shehabaldeen/) on 2018-08-17**:
I have another question, is it necessary to have URDF model even if I will not simulate the robot I just want to interface it directly to hardware?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2018-08-17**:
Yes. I had already removed everything from the URDF that is only necessary for simulation. But your URDF could even be much simpler than my example; for example, the caster wheels could be deleted. Also you don't even need the visual and collision tags for your purpose.

**Comment by [ShehabAldeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/31455/shehabaldeen/) on 2018-08-17**:
Thanks a ton